# PHP interface to manage linux user accounts

Tags: users, php

I have a linux web & samba server. I need to give administrators access to manage minor accounts & groups. Is there a secure php web interface that can do this? I don't want to give them shell access, but they need to be able to change passwords, create, & manage accounts\groups. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at [webmin](http://webmin.com). Not sure that it allows fine-grained controls.

Comment: I installed webmin. I am surprised how good it is. I created a user, and was able to restrict all access, except what I needed. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

this is more than an interface such as Webmin, but a Ubuntu based distribution with OpenLDAP, Samba, nice GUI with user self service, and lots more.... [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org/)